# Editing Alfresco Default User and Site Dashboard Layout / Dashlets

Tags: content-management-system, alfresco

For my specific implementation, it makes sense to only use the 2 column layout on both the site and user dashboards. I want to make this the default layout and pick which dashlets I'm going to use, as I'm going to create a large number of sites and users and don't want to manually go through and edit the layout for each one.

I've successfully commented-out sections of the `presets.xml` located in `/tomcat/webapps/share/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/site-data/presets` such that when I create a new user, only the dashlets left uncommented are shown, however the dashlets are still shown in the 3 column layout. If anyone could tell me what I'd need to edit to make this layout default and/or how to define the region-id's, I'd be extremely grateful.

I've been looking for where the user's layout config is stored so I could set the dashboard up as I want it to be in the preset and then look at this user's config to get figure out how to put this in as the default in `presets.xml` but I can't find where they're put.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pow: http://forums.alfresco.com/en/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=37001&p=107959#p107959

Answer (score 1):

http://mafshan89.blogspot.in/2012/05/dashboard-customization-for-existing.html

see if this helps...

Comment: While the link may help, it would be better if you at least paraphrased what it is explaining.